# What is non-proprietary memory?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

I have seen advertisements for "non-proprietary memory". What does that mean?

Comment: The cynic in me wants to say: It is what it sounds like. It's advertisers throwing around big words again trying to get your money.

Comment: Perhaps an example?

Comment: Several here http://www.buy.com/retail/usersearchresults.asp?store=1&querytype=comp&qu=non-proprietary+memory&loc=101&qxt=comp&display=col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the design of the memory has no [mask work protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit_layout_design_protection) and can be copied and distributed by anyone. I have used this type of memory before and found it works just as well and half the price.